# TypeError: '>' not supported between instances of 'str' and 'int' to show the number of 1s in binary

Tags: python

I'm attempting to use the Boolean logic to perform bitwise and operations between 2 numbers through iterations to find the number of 1s in the binary.

```
import string

def main():
    binary_1 = input("Enter a number in terms of binary: ")
    binary_1 = str(binary_1)
    denary_1 = int(binary_1, 2)
    denary_2 = int(denary_1 - 1)

    count = 0

    while denary_1 > 0:
        denary_1 = bin(denary_1 & denary_2)
        count = count + 1

    print (count)

main()
```

When the program was run:

```
Enter a number in terms of binary: 1001
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/Owner/Documents/University/Summer work/Introduction to Python/Extra work/count_number_of_1s_7.py", line 17, in <module>
    main()
  File "C:/Users/Owner/Documents/University/Summer work/Introduction to Python/Extra work/count_number_of_1s_7.py", line 11, in main
    while denary_1 > 0:
TypeError: '>' not supported between instances of 'str' and 'int'
```

I was expecting the program to output a line stating the number of 1s in the binary.

I have made some modifications into the program:

```
import string

def main():
    binary_1 = input("Enter a number in terms of binary: ")
    denary_1 = int(binary_1, 2)
    denary_2 = denary_1 - 1

    count = 0

    while denary_1 > 0:
        denary_1 = denary_1 & denary_2
        count = count + 1

    print (count)

main()
```

After running the program, it seems to be frozen on this:
Enter a number in terms of binary: 1001
where the program is keep running.

Comment: `input` already returns a `str`; `binary_1 = str(binary_1)` is redundant.

Comment: `return sum( digit == '1' for digit in binary_1)` ?

Comment: `bin`, however, returns a `str`, making `denary_1` a `str` (not an `int`) on subsequent iterations of the `while` loop.

Comment: @PatrickArtner even better  `binary_1.count('1')`

Comment: Can you explain what you expect `denary_1 = denary_1 & denary_2` to mean? If you do this repeatedly, the result isn't going to change more than once, because `a & a == a`, so if `denary_1 > 0` is not true after the first iteration, it will never be true and you have an infinite loop.

Comment: @mkrieger denary_1 = denary_1 & denary_2 means the repetition of the Boolean AND operation between n and n - 1 where n is represented by denary_1  and n - 1 is represented by denary_2.

Comment: But `denary_1 - 1` is only evaluated once at the beginning. Apparently you want to evaluate it in every iteration.

Comment: @mkrieger1 , thank you, the formula does need to be included in the iteration.

Answer (score 0):

if you want to count the numbers of 1s from the bynary number:

```
def main():
    binary_1 = input("Enter a number in terms of binary: ")
    print(binary_1.count('1'))

main()
# enter 1001
# output: 2
```

your code was freezing because your while loop will run forever (denary_1 will be equal with denary_2 and will be equal with 8 and 8 is forever > 0)

Answer (score 0):

Problem is here:

```
denary_1 = bin(denary_1 & denary_2)
```

By second iteration the type has been changed to string format.

About bin : https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#bin

You should be doing this to get right count (Brian Kernighan’s Algorithm):

```
denary_1 = denary_1 & (denary_1-1)  # resets the last bit set.
```